# How can I implement a workflow for a pre existing MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

How can I implement a workflow structure for a pre existing MVC application?

i already have a working web application in asp.net MVC. Now it is required to implement certain parts of the application with the workflow structure.Is it possible?Are there any engines or code generators with which i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Usually Workflow Foundation is implemented as a Windows Service exposing a WCF endpoint for interacting with instances of workflows.  Then your MVC app would make calls to this service using WCF.  Learning WWF is a very different thing than learning or working with ASP.NET MVC.  It is best to think of them as two different systems, just as the web app is different than the database. Also to help design a workflow in WWF, your question would need more details.